# Add bottom border of to tabs in Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart, flutter-layout

What I'm trying to do is adding a bottom border of tabBar, so it will be under tabs title and above the indicatorColor and for both active and Inactive tabs, just like the attached image.

**Red line is what I am trying to add, green line is the indicatorColor.**

*Note, usually I do this for appBar using 'bottom' but here bottom is reserved to the TabBar*.

Is this possible?

Thanks a lot

[image: Flutter tabs screen]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can set the AppBar `shape` property as abdulrahmanAbdullah says. But if you strictly need the border above the indicator, you can put it inside of each tab bar item. Here's one take on it:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(TabBarDemo());
}



class TabBarDemo extends StatelessWidget {

  Widget _createTab(String text) {
    return Tab(
      child: Row(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
        children: [
          Expanded(
            child: Container(
              child: Center(child: Text(text)),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(border: Border(bottom: BorderSide(color: Colors.black)))
            )
          ),
        ]
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData(
        primaryColor: Colors.white,
      ),
      home: DefaultTabController(
        length: 3,
        child: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            elevation: 0,
            bottom: TabBar(
              labelPadding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
              tabs: [
                _createTab("Tab 1"),
                _createTab("Tab 2"),
                _createTab("Tab 3"),
              ],
            ),
            title: Text('Tabs Demo'),
          ),
          body: TabBarView(
            children: [
              Icon(Icons.directions_car),
              Icon(Icons.directions_transit),
              Icon(Icons.directions_bike),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Nice work! So simple, more than my own solution, so I considered it. Thanks a lot.

Comment: If i have 5 tabs, and each have same width as above so how can i show it so that i can scroll them horizontally?

Answer (score 7):

Try to set appBar border :

```
appBar: AppBar(
    shape: Border(bottom: BorderSide(color: Colors.red)),
     ....
```

Comment: what you suggested is too close, it's only under the indicatorColor. I did it using the solution I just posted. Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: there is no appBar  within TabBar

Answer (score 7):

Simply you can wrap **TabBar** into **DecoratedBox** as below:

```
DecoratedBox(
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
    //This is for background color
    color: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.0),

    //This is for bottom border that is needed
    border: Border(
        bottom: BorderSide(color: AppColors.color4, width: 2.sp)),
    ),
    child: TabBar(
        ...
    ),
),
```

[image]

Hope you will get help.

Comment: It sets bottom side border color for all inactive tabs, not for active one. Not sure how you get that output in the screenshot.

Answer (score 3):

I managed to do that using '**flexibleSpace**' property instead 'bottom' property, as flexibleSpace can have any widget not only 'PreferredSizeWidget' like bottom.

So I gave a Column to the flexibleSpace, then I was able to put TabBar and the container inside that column, then using Matrix4.translationValues(0.0, -2.6, 0.0) I gave the container, which contain the border, a nigative-padding(or similar) so it moved to the top of the indicatorColor.

```dart
return SafeArea(
  top: true,
  child: Scaffold(
    appBar: PreferredSize(
      preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(100.0),
      child: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).buttonColor,
        title: Text(
          'AppBar',
          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
          style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.title,
        ),
        centerTitle: true,
        elevation: 0.0,
        flexibleSpace: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 50.0),
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              // Tab Bar
              new TabBar(
                indicatorColor: Theme.of(context).accentColor,
                tabs: <Tab>[
                  new Tab(
                    text: 'Tab1',
                  ),
                  new Tab(
                    text: 'Tab2',
                  ),
                ],
                controller: _tabController,
              ),
              // Border
              Container(
                // Negative padding
                transform: Matrix4.translationValues(0.0, -2.6, 0.0),
                // Add top border
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                   border: Border(
                     top: BorderSide(
                        color: Color(0xFFc3c3c3),
                        width: 0.6,
                     ),
                   ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
    body: new TabBarView(
      children: <Widget>[
        new Tab1(),
        new Tab2(),
      ],
      controller: _tabController,
    ),
  ),
);
```

**And the magic happened ^^**

[image: TabBar with border]

Answer (score 3):

Another approach is to use a stack and place the line underneath the tabs

```
               Stack(
                  alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                  children: [
                    Container(
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          border: Border(
                        bottom: BorderSide(color: Colors.white70, width: 1),
                      )),
                    ),
                    TabBar(
                      indicatorWeight: 3.0,
                      tabs: [
                        Tab(
                          icon: Icon(Icons.home),
                        ),
                        Tab(
                          icon: Icon(Icons.show_chart),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's my version of [spenster's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57333635/7378293);

Instead of a function, I created a new widget "BorderedTab" which implements Tab:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class BorderedTab extends StatelessWidget implements Tab {
  const BorderedTab({
    Key key,
    this.text,
    this.borderColor=Colors.grey,
    this.width=0.5,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final String text;
  final Color borderColor;
  final double width;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Tab(
      child: Row(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
          children: [
            Expanded(
                child: Container(
                    child: Center(
                        child: Text(text)
                    ),
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        border: Border(
                            bottom: BorderSide(
                                width: width,
                                color: borderColor,
                            ),
                        ),
                    ),
                ),
            ),
          ]
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  // TODO: implement child
  Widget get child => null;

  @override
  // TODO: implement icon
  Widget get icon => null;
}
```

then I used BorderedTab just like the regular Tab, but with:

`labelPadding: EdgeInsets.all(0.0), // Important to remove default padding`

Final AppBar:

```dart
import 'package:../widgets/bordered_tab.dart';

...

appBar: AppBar(
  backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).buttonColor,
  title: Text(
    'TabBar',
    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
    style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.title,
  ),
  centerTitle: true,
  elevation: 0.0,
  bottom: new TabBar(
    labelColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
    indicatorColor:Theme.of(context).accentColor,
    labelPadding: EdgeInsets.all(0.0), // Important to remove default padding
    tabs: <Tab>[
      BorderedTab(
        text: 'Tab1',
        borderColor: Color(0xFFc3c3c3),
      ),
      BorderedTab(
        text: 'Tab2',
        borderColor: Color(0xFFc3c3),
      ),
    ],
    controller: _tabController,
  ),
),
```

Comment: Thanks for the labelPadding hint!

Answer (score 1):

I would like to add an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69796449/17320508)

all answers have a problem due to which the bottom line is either higher or lower than the indicator, and it is also quite difficult to control its height.

Well. here is a working version in flutter 3

```
                  PreferredSize(
                    preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(kToolbarHeight),
                    child: DecoratedBox(
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        border: Border(
                          bottom: BorderSide(
                            color: AppColors.border,
                            width: 3,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      child: TabBar(
                        labelColor: AppColors.secondText,
                        unselectedLabelColor: AppColors.grayText,
                        indicator: UnderlineTabIndicator(
                          borderSide: BorderSide(
                              width: 3.0, color: AppColors.secondText),
                          insets: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 30.0),
                        ),
                        tabs: [
                          Tab(
                            text: "Tab 1",
                          ),
                          Tab(
                            text: "Tab 2",
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
```

Answer (score 0):

**Use DecoratedBox and PreferredSize**

First put **TabBar** inside of **PreferredSize** :

```
child: AppBar(
      bottom: PreferredSize(
        preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(50),
        child: TabBar(
          tabs: [
            Tab(
              text: 'tab-1',
            ),
            Tab(
              text: 'tab-2',
            ),
            Tab(
              text: 'tab-3',
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ),
```

then wrap **TabBar** with **DecoratedBox**

```
child: AppBar(
      bottom: PreferredSize(
        preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(50),
        child: DecoratedBox(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            border: Border(bottom: BorderSide(width: 2,color: Color.fromARGB(255, 255, 0, 0)))
          ),
          child: TabBar(
            tabs: [
              Tab(
                text: 'tab-1',
              ),
              Tab(
                text: 'tab-2',
              ),
              Tab(
                text: 'tab-3',
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
```

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way without using additional elements, is to use BoxShadow with TabBar like below:

```
TabBar(
                        controller: _tabController,
                        indicator: BoxDecoration(
                                                 boxShadow: [
                            BoxShadow(
                              color: Colors.red,                         
                              offset: Offset(0, 2.0),
                            )
                          ],
                        
                          color: Colors.white,
                        ),
                        labelColor: Colors.red,
                        unselectedLabelColor: Colors.grey.shade900,
                        labelPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10.0),
                        isScrollable: false,
                        tabs: [
                          Tab(
                            text: 'T1',
                          ),
                          Tab(
                            text: 'T2',
                          ),
                          Tab(
                            text: 'T3',
                          ),
                          Tab(
                            text: 'T4',
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
```

Or using  UnderlineTabIndicator as indicator parameter of TabBar:

```
indicator: UnderlineTabIndicator(
                  borderSide: BorderSide(width: 3.0),
                  insets: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 30.0),
                ),
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `TabBar` `dividerColor` property.